# current-dateTime() to number

Tags: date, xslt, type-conversion

I need to convert the current-dateTime() to a number, because the output only allows an integer (or long). How can I do that?

My desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<currentDate>NaN</currentDate>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="version" select="'1.0'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="currentDate">
            <xsl:value-of select="number(current-dateTime())"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>        

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I get this here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<currentDate>NaN</currentDate>
```

When I remove the number() I do get the timestamp, but I need to have a clean number.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<currentDate>2014-01-15T07:01:02.526+01:00</currentDate>
```

**How can I convert the timestamp to a clean number?**

Comment: Is the number you want the unix style integer time?

Comment: No that's not necessary. 20140115070102526 would be ok for the above timestamp 2014-01-15T07:01:02.526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, to convert "2014-01-15T07:01:02.526+01:00" to "20140115070102526" you can use the translate() function (this would work with XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(string(current-dateTime()), 1, 23), '-:T.', '')"/>
```

Alternatively, you can calculate the duration between the current date and time and an arbitrary start and divide this duration by a millisecond to get the number of milliseconds since that date:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime('1971-01-01T00:00:00')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S')"/>
```

Comment: I used this: <xsl:value-of select="replace(string(current-dateTime()), '[^0-9]', '')"/>

Comment: Minor correction: current-dateTime() is a 2.0 function, so it won't work in 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0, you can use the [`format-dateTime()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date) and reformat the date: just use a *picture* parameter with no separators.

Alternatively - assuming all component values are already padded with zeros to maintain a fixed length - you could simply translate the separator characters away.

Comment: I used this: <xsl:value-of select="replace(string(current-dateTime()), '[^0-9]', '')"/>

Comment: @FiveO Since I did not suggest using replace(), the code for it has no place in my answer.